# Find out constant value by given string in c

Tags: c, string

Need to check Is the given string constant value (int/long/double) or not?

Here strtol function is used to find constant value. But facing problem

Example :

```
   if(li1 = strtol (str,NULL,0))
       printf("valid Integer ...");
```

1. `str = "1"` output = 1.00
2. `str = "0.99999"` output = 0.00
3. `str = "tab"` output = 0.00

Then how to differentiate between "0.99999" and "tab" by looking at output?

Comment: Why not `strtof` or `strtod` if you might be handling floats?

Answer (score 3):

For integers, [`strtol`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/) provides the second argument which will be set to point to the first unconvertible character.

If it's anything other the the null terminator `\0`, then there was rubbish at the end of the number. If it's equal to the original string, then *no* suitable characters were found.

Example:

```
char *str = "72";

char *estr;
float val = strtol (str, &estr, 10);
if (estr == str) {
    // there was no convertible characters.
}
if (*estr != '\0') {
    // there was rubbish at the end.
}
if (errno != 0) {
    // underflow/overflow.
}
```

For floating point, you need to use one of the [`strtoX`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtof/) functions.

It acts very similar to the `strtol` function.

Example usage:

```
char *str = "0.9999";

char *estr;
float val = strtof (str, &estr);
if (estr == str) {
    // there was no convertible characters.
}
if (*estr != '\0') {
    // there was rubbish at the end.
}
if (errno != 0) {
    // underflow/overflow.
}
```

---

A function to work out what type a string represented is shown in the complete program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define TYP_INTEGRAL 0
#define TYP_FLOATING 1
#define TYP_BAD      2
int getTypeAndData (char *str, long *valL, float *valF) {
    char *end;

    *valL = strtol (str, &end, 10);
    if ((end != str) && (*end == '\0'))
        return TYP_INTEGRAL;

    *valF = strtof (str, &end);
    if ((end != str) && (*end == '\0'))
        return TYP_FLOATING;

    return TYP_BAD;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *desc[] = {"INT", "FLT", "BAD"};
    int i, typ;
    long lvar;
    float fvar;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        lvar = 0; fvar = 0;
        typ = getTypeAndData (argv[i], &lvar, &fvar);
        printf ("%s: [%-10s] %10ld %10.3f\n", desc[typ], argv[i], lvar, fvar);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run with `myprog 12345 hello 12.7 1e2 0.4 .1 "" 0`, the output is:

```
INT: [12345     ]      12345      0.000
BAD: [hello     ]          0      0.000
FLT: [12.7      ]         12     12.700
FLT: [1e2       ]          1    100.000
FLT: [0.4       ]          0      0.400
FLT: [.1        ]          0      0.100
BAD: [          ]          0      0.000
INT: [0         ]          0      0.000
```

and you can see it's detecting at least the unit test cases I could come up with quickly.

Note that this doesn't directly communicate underflow and overflow conditions. The default values are returned in those cases since they are usually the sensible options, but you can check `errno` after returning if you want to catch those conditions.

Comment: I wish I could +2 - one for a great post and one for the term "wetware."

Comment: In your first two you might need to check `errno` against specific values to make sure it's not still set from a previous function (though I suppose if it was the caller ought to have handled the error and reset it manually?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Its not working for following test cases 

1. 10L ===> float constant

2. 10xyz ===> not a constant

Comment: @ashwini, that's because `10L` is not a valid integer or float according to the `strtoX` rules (although it's valid in C source). If you want to accept as valid numbers outside the `strtoX` scope, your code will be much more complex. It's doable but not with those functions alone (best bet is to probably pre-massage the string to remove trailing `L/LL/UL/ULL/etc). I would suggest opening up a separate question asking for a function that does that (and specifying _everything_ you need). As for `10xyz`, that isn't valid even as a constant in C so I'm not sure why you'd want to accept that.